# cd express_example && npm install error

Tags: bash, express, npm, installation

I'm pretty new to the node community and such there are a lot of errors I get that I don't know how to fix. Recently I was trying out a tutorial from  http://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/ to learn Node and Express, but I immediately got stuck at the beginning installation part: "cd express_example && npm install"

**I'm on terminal for mac, and receive this error:
<>-bash: cd: express_example: No such file or directory**

I don't understand how you can install something with a cd reference at the beginning, I've searched around for a solution, but no one seems to be encountering this issue. If you could direct me to how to solve it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you follow all steps?

Comment: You appear to have missed a direction or two before that step.

Comment: You need to rephrase this into a question, and give details of what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you follow all steps (assuming `npm` is already installed):

Install express-generator:

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

Create application under `express_example`:

```
express -c stylus express_example
```

Now execute the command you wanted (**do not** change the directory):

```
cd express_example && npm install
```

Comment: Thank you! I believe that's exactly what happened: I changed the directory.

Comment: @MianmaGugeti no problem, happens to all of us :)